# Android browser file upload only allows video files by default

Tags: android, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I'm working on a web application for mobile phones and when I tested the file upload (you know the html input type=file tag) on the Samsung Galaxy S3 it only allowed me to select a video file or to record a new video. The phone wouldn't let me choose an image or switch the camera mode to a still photo.

So, how do you get android to play nice with the  tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple, you need to add the attribute Accept="image/*" like this:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

If you're using the asp:FileUpload like me then the only way you can add this attribute is with javascript (the only way I'm aware of). This is how I did it with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=file]").attr("accept", "image/*");
}
```